# Returns Generic type Database result set in C#

Tags: c#, oop, interface, generic-list

I wrote a concrete class to expose database result set which includes T-type list items and total row count. After some reading(*Dependency inversion principle, Interface segregation principle*), I found that it should expose as Interface rather than concrete class.

Here is my code, what is the best way to write this class to expose as an `IDbResultSet` rather exposing as `DbResultSet`.

```
public class DbResultSet<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; private set; }
    public int TotalRowCount { get; private set; }

    public DbResultSet(List<T> items, int totalRowCount)
    {
        this.Items = items;
        this.TotalRowCount = totalRowCount;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
DbResultSet<Category> GetCategory(int categoryId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no much you can do. It's just about designing the interface:

```
public interface IDbResultSet<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : ICollection<T>
{
     TCollection Items { get; }
     int TotalRowCount { get; }
}
```

As you can check above, the whole interface has no defined `Items` collection type: it can be any collection which implements `ICollection<T>`.

Now you may implement it as follows:

```
public class DbResultSet<T, TCollection> : IDbResultSet<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : ICollection<T> 
{
    public TCollection  Items { get; private set; }
    public int TotalRowCount { get; private set; }

    public DbResultSet(TCollection items, int totalRowCount)
    {
        // Note that qualifying with "this" is redundant here
        // so I've removed it
        Items = items;
        TotalRowCount = totalRowCount;
    }
}
```

BTW, I would suggest you that you should change both the interface and class name from `ResultSet` to `Result` *as is*, because a *set* is a collection type on which there's no order but collection items are *unique*:

```
public interface IDbResult<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : ICollection<T>
{
     TCollection Items { get; }
     int TotalRowCount { get; }
}

public class DbResult<T, TCollection> : IDbResultSet<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : ICollection<T> 
{
    public TCollection  Items { get; private set; }
    public int TotalRowCount { get; private set; }

    public DbResult(TCollection items, int totalRowCount)
    {
        // Note that qualifying with "this" is redundant here
        // so I've removed it
        Items = items;
        TotalRowCount = totalRowCount;
    }
}
```

Therefore, you may expose your results typed as interface types:

```
IDbResult<Category, IList<Category>> GetCategories();
```

### Some advise

I see that you want to use that approach even for *a single result*:

```
 DbResultSet<Category> GetCategory(int categoryId);
```

My suggestion is that you should then split your results into *two families*:

- Single result.
- Multiple results.

So I would end up with these interfaces:

```
public interface IMultipleDbResult<T, TCollection>
       where TCollection : ICollection<T>
{
     TCollection Items { get; }
     int TotalRowCount { get; }
}

public interface ISingleDbResult<T>
{
      T Item { get; }
}
```

I'm suggesting you this because it's odd that you know that you're getting *a category by `Id`* and you may need to get it from a list:

```
IDbResult<Category, IList<Category>> result = GetCategoryById(389);
Category category = result.Items[0]; // ??????

// vs.

ISingleDbResult<Category> result = GetCategoryById(389);
Category category = result.Item; // Isn't it more elegant?
```

BTW, I understand that your actual solution involves implementing more properties on both result types. For example to collect DB query error messages or other useful data.

In the other hand, I guess you're implementing a property like `TotalRowCount` because you're paginating results. For example, there could be 300 categories but `Items` property holds *10 items* from the first page. Otherwise, your reasoning has some flaw, because all implementations of `ICollection<T>` already own a `Count` property.

Finally, perhaps be of interested on some design pattern I've published online. See [*Accmulated Result design pattern*](http://designpattern.ninja/catalog/design-patterns/accumulated-result).

Comment: You nailed it. You have answered all most all the questions that I had on my mind eg: SingleResult concept. Cheers!

Comment: @Aruna No problem! You're welcome. Take a look at the design pattern I've suggested you, it might be your definitive bet :)